# How can I get a Users Firstname in a Grails filter

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my GSP I have the following...

```
<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="givenName"/>
```

How would I do this same thing in a Grails filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just inject the spring security service into your filter. For example:

```
package com.example

class MyFilters {
  def springSecurityService

  def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
      before = {
        println springSecurityService.principal.givenName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dope I didn't think you could but I will try again. If this is the case what is the use of the static Util class? Wouldn't I just use this to get roles?

Comment: I'm positive you can inject services into a filter, I do so often. The case of the utils class is for cases where you can't access the service.

Comment: If you use this approach you'll need to implement a custom `UserDetailsService` that adds `givenName` to the `UserDetails` impementation returned thereby

Comment: Good point. I just assumed that was the case, because for me it usually is.

Comment: For data like this that doesn't change and you want to access, a custom UserDetails makes sense. Otherwise change `principal` to `currentUser` and it will load the whole instance from the db